# Select virtual column is not working in where condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I'm trying to do is doing some calculation in select and assign it as virtual variable like **as TimeDiff** but when I'm trying to use it in where condition it says unknown column.

I try 2 ways both fails :

1 :

```
SELECT `AL`.`UserID`, ROUND(IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(AL.CreatedDate), MAX(AL.CreatedDate)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0), 0)) as TimeDiff FROM (`ActiveLogins` AL) LEFT JOIN `Users` U ON `U`.`UserID`=`AL`.`UserID` WHERE `U`.`StatusID` IN (1, 2) AND TimeDiff>0 AND TimeDiff<86401 GROUP BY `AL`.`UserID`
```

2 :

```
SELECT `AL`.`UserID`, @TimeDiff := ROUND(IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(AL.CreatedDate), MAX(AL.CreatedDate)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0), 0)) as TimeDiff FROM (`ActiveLogins` AL) LEFT JOIN `Users` U ON `U`.`UserID`=`AL`.`UserID` WHERE `U`.`StatusID` IN (1, 2) AND @TimeDiff>0 AND @TimeDiff<86401 GROUP BY `AL`.`UserID`
```

In 2nd query there's no error but also there's no records return but records do exists in table there's just 2 column in table UserID and CreatedDate in ActiveLogin Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Alias name` in same `select` query `where` clause. Add the filter in outer query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT `al`.`userid`, 
               Round(Ifnull(Timestampdiff(second, Min(al.createddate), 
                            Max(al.createddate)) / 
                                  Nullif(Count(*) - 1, 0), 0)) AS timediff 
        FROM   `activelogins` al 
               LEFT JOIN `users` u 
                      ON `u`.`userid` = `al`.`userid` 
                     AND  `u`.`statusid` IN ( 1, 2 )) a 
WHERE  timediff > 0 
       AND timediff < 86401 
GROUP  BY `userid`
```

This is how query is logically processed

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10 ORDER BY
11. TOP
```

As you can see `SELECT` comes after `WHERE` clause you cannot use the *alias name* in `where` generated in `select`

Comment: it returns only 1 result

Comment: @BillGates - check now. Moved the filter to ON condition, since it is a right table filter

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HAVING keyword for aggregated Columns

```
SELECT 
  `AL`.`UserID`, 
  ROUND(IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(AL.CreatedDate), MAX(AL.CreatedDate)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0), 0)) as TimeDiff 
FROM 
  (`ActiveLogins` AL) LEFT JOIN `Users` U ON `U`.`UserID`=`AL`.`UserID` 
WHERE 
  `U`.`StatusID` IN (1, 2) 
HAVING 
  TimeDiff>0 AND TimeDiff<86401 
GROUP BY 
  `AL`.`UserID`
```